# Error: No operator '+=' matches float and Vector2 in fluid simulation property gradient calculation

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point, operator-overloading

I'm trying to follow [Sebastian Lague's Fluid simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSKMYc1CQHE) video in c++ and OpenGL. I'm at the point where we calculate a `propertyGradient` value (timestamp is 14:15).
I'll try to provide all the code that is relevant further down below.

```
float CalculatePropertyGradient(Vector2 samplePoint, const std::vector<Vector2>& positions, const std::vector<float>& particleProperties, float smoothingRadius, float mass)
{
    float propertyGradient = 0.0f;
    DensityCalculator calculator(positions, smoothingRadius); 
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
    {
        float dst = (positions[i] - samplePoint).magnitude();
        Vector2 dir = (positions[i] - samplePoint) / dst;
        float slope = SmoothingKernelDerivative(dst, smoothingRadius);
        float density = calculator.CalculateDensity(positions[i]); 
        Vector2 scaledDir = dir * particleProperties[i];
        propertyGradient += -(scaledDir) * slope *  mass / density;
    }
    return propertyGradient;
}
```

But I'm getting a syntax error in the line:

`propertyGradient += -(scaledDir) * slope *  mass / density;`
under += operator that my Vector2 class doesn't support this operation involving float and vector2

My vector2 class:

```
class Vector2 {
public:
    float X;
    float Y;

    Vector2(float x, float y) : X(x), Y(y) {}

    float magnitude() const {
        return sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
    }

    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& other) const {
        return Vector2(X - other.X, Y - other.Y);
    }

    Vector2 operator/(const float& scalar) const {
        return Vector2(X / scalar, Y / scalar);
    }

    Vector2 operator*(const float& right) const {
        return Vector2(X * right, Y * right);
    }

    Vector2 operator-(const float& scalar) const {
        return Vector2(X - scalar, Y - scalar);
    }

    Vector2 operator*(const Vector2& other) const {
        return Vector2(X * other.X, Y * other.Y);
    }
    Vector2 Zero() {
        return Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    
    Vector2 operator-() const {
        return Vector2(-X, -Y);
    }
    Vector2& operator+=(const float& scalar) {
        X += scalar;
        Y += scalar;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

My density class:

```
class DensityCalculator {
private:
    std::vector<float> densities;
    std::vector<Vector2> positions;
    float smoothingRadius;

public:
    DensityCalculator(const std::vector<Vector2>& positions, float smoothingRadius)
        : positions(positions), smoothingRadius(smoothingRadius) {}

    void PreCalculateDensities() {
        densities.clear();
        for (const auto& position : positions) {
            densities.push_back(CalculateDensity(position));
        }
    }

    float CalculateDensity(Vector2 position) const {
        float density = 0;
        const float mass = 1;

        for (const auto& p : positions) {
            float dst = (p - position).magnitude();
            if (dst <= smoothingRadius) {
                float influence = SmoothingKernel(smoothingRadius, dst);
                density += mass * influence;
            }
        }
        return density;

    }

    float GetDensity(int index) const {
        return densities[index];
    }
};
```

SmoothingKernel and SmoothingKernelDerivative functions:

```
float SmoothingKernel(float radius, float dst)
{
    if (dst < radius)
    {
        float volume = M_PI * pow(radius, 8) / 4;
        float v = std::max(radius * radius - dst * dst, 0.0f);
        return ((v * v * v) / volume);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
static float SmoothingKernelDerivative(float dst, float radius)
{
    if (dst >= radius)
        return 0;
    float f = radius * radius - dst * dst;
    float scale = -24 / (M_PI * pow(radius, 8));
    return scale * dst * f * f;
}
```

Here's the function call in my main function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
        float x = distX(mt);
        float y = distY(mt);
        balls.emplace_back(x, y, 0.0, 0.0, radius);

        // Calculate the value of ExampleFunction at the particle's location and store it in particleProperties
        float propertyValue = ExampleFunction(Vector2(x, y));
        particleProperties.push_back(propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Where ExampleFunction is just

```
static float ExampleFunction(Vector2(pos))
{
    return cos(pos.Y - 3 + sin(pos.X));
}
```

I've tried **declaring the operator += of vector2 as acting on a const object** as suggested by another post but i get an error that X and Y must be a modifiable value.

Comment: Well, `propertyGradient` is a float (i.e. a scalar). How were you proposing to add a vector (some multiple of `scaledDir`)to a scalar?

Comment: I don't think you would need so much code to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @lastchance I have a member function at the end of the Vector2 class but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue

Comment: @Realm07 Can you create an example that we can just copy/paste into the compilers and reproduce the problem. Just remove all the unnecessary code(i.e., code that has nothing to do with error) and provide the minimal version.

Comment: But you are attempting to do scalar += vector, whilst your member function is trying to do vector += scalar, even if either of those operations made physical sense.

Comment: @user12002570 I tried to do as you asked. Please let me know if this works. I'm still new to c++ and SO.  https://pastebin.com/v4b2d7Rj

Comment: @Realm07 I've modified your code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8M36s5rxK) so that it works. I've put some comments there so that you can see what changes I made there. I've given the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78135498/12002570)

Comment: To be honest, given the other operations in that function - and the actual physics involved - it looks as if ```propertyGradient``` would be better as a vector anyway, with components that are the derivative in the two coordinate directions. More importantly, IN THAT VIDEO THAT YOU CITE (at timestamp 14:15) ```propertyGradient``` IS A VECTOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that currently the overloaded `operator+=(const float&)` that you've provided takes the right hand operand which is a `float` instead of `Vector2`.

Now, the expression `scaledDir * mass` is of type `Vector2` which means that you're trying to use `operator+=` with right hand operand of type `Vector2`. But since you haven't provided any such `opertor+=` that takes right hand operand of type `Vector2`, you get the mentioned error.

---

To solve this, just provide an overload that takes an operand of type `Vector2`. One way of doing this is as shown below:

```
//----------------------------vvvvvvv---------->changed float to Vector2
    Vector2& operator+=(const Vector2& vec) {
        X += vec.X;
        Y += vec.Y;
        return *this;
    }
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fvMozzenz)

Answer (score 1):

Since `scaledDir` is a `Vector2`, `-scaleDir` is also a `Vector2`. Multiplying it with `slope` results in a `Vector2`. Etc.

So the result of the expression `-(scaledDir) * slope *  mass / density` is a `Vector2` object, which can't be added to the `float` variable `propertyGradient`.

Your `operator+=` is for a `Vector2` on the **left**-hand side, not right.

You either need a temporary `Vector2` variable, and use its `magnitude` function to add to `propertyGradient`. Or an implicit conversion operator which calls `magnitude` (which more often than not a bad idea).